# How to get value of a control in a Masterpage using JQuery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a hidden field control in a `MasterPage` and I want to get the value of the hidden field control using JQuery in a page that uses the `MasterPage`.

I have the following javascript which exectues if the hidden field in the page has a value:

```
if(!$('input[type=hidden]').val().length == 0 ) { }
```

What javascript would I need to check the value of a hidden field in the `MasterPage` from the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no seperation between your page and the master page. Both of those concepts are in your ASP.NET layer and the browser simply recieves one HTML document.

If your masterpage specified a hidden input it'll be on your page like any other hidden input.

Answer (score 3):

If that has the affect you want, it should also work in the masterpage, as there is no difference on the client between a master and a content page.

Answer (score 2):

The master page just gets rendered down with the child page as a single HTML, so you would just access it client-side as normal.

Try rewriting this:

```
if(!$('input[type=hidden]').val().length == 0 ) { }
```

as

```
if ($('input[type=hidden]').val()) {}
```

which is a simpler conditional for if the hidden field has a value. I'm not sure that the `!` combined with the `==` is doing what you want it to do logically. Either way `$('input[type=hidden]').val()` is more readable IMO.